# Add widget/shortcode to sidebar OUTSIDE of the theme

Tags: shortcode, widgets, sidebar

I have a theme that shows a boxed layout. Meaning that on the left and right side there is space where no widget can be placed. I'd like to add advertisement there through a plugin, for this I need to place a shortcode there. How would I accomplish this, where can I start to look?

I'm obviously a beginner and my search here and on google hasn't brought me the right answer, probably because I don't know the right keywords to search for.

Answer (score 0):

The theme files control the spaces and containers. So the Code for Ads is needed to be placed in theme template file. In general, first you need to create space for the ads in the template file, and add the ads code in the file.